# Expanding existing class instance in Python

Tags: python, selenium, class, inheritance

I have an object `element` that is returned by another class method I don't necessarily have access to change.

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
>>> browser = Chrome()
>>> browser.get('https://www.google.com')
>>> element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
>>> type(element)
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
```

I have a separate class that extends the functionality of the element.

```
>>> class Input:
>>>     def __init__(self, element):
>>>         assert element.tag_name == 'input', 'Element must be of type "input"'
>>>         self.element = element
>>>         self.browser = element.parent
>>>     def is_enabled(self):
>>>         return self.element.is_enabled()
>>>     @property
>>>     def value(self):
>>>         return self.element.get_attribute('value')
```

Currently the way I use this is by passing `element` into the class:

```
>>> input = Input(element)
>>> input.is_enabled() # Same as input.element.is_enabled()
True
```

I want to be able to more easily access the original object's attributes rather than having to specify it in the call. For example:

Instead of this:

```
>>> input.element.tag_name
'input'
```

Do this:

```
>>> input.tag_name
'input'
```

How would I implement something like this?

Comment: You need the proxy pattern. You can forward attribute accesses to the contained `element`.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `Input` class to be a proxy by implementing the `__getattr__()` method, like the `Container` class below:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tag_name = 'name'
    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'
    def bar(self, param):
        return param

class Container:
    def __init__(self, contained):
        self.contained = contained

    def zoo(self):
        return 0

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if hasattr(self.contained, item):
            return getattr(self.contained,item)
        #raise item

c = Container(Example())
print(c.foo())
print(c.bar('BAR'))
print(c.tag_name)
```

Output:

```
foo
BAR
name
```

The `Container` class now forwards any unknown attribute accesses to its `contained` member, which of course, may or may not have the required attribute.